# Differential equation: $y'=y^2/x-1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does anyone know how to find a general solution (or a particular solution, if a general solution is not feasible) to the following differential equation?

$$y'=\frac{y^2}{x}-1$$

This isn't separable, and Laplace transforms don't work out nicely. I've also tried a whole bunch of substitutions, none of which have led to a more manageable differential equation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me why this works, or if there's any possible way of generalising it, but if you put (bear with me)
$$ y= -x\frac{u'}{u}, $$
you find that the equation becomes
$$ \frac{u-u'-xu''}{u} = 0, $$
which is a nice ordinary second-order ODE, related to Bessel's equation. It has solutions
$$ u = A I_0(2\sqrt{x})+ BK_0(2\sqrt{x}), $$
from which it is easy to get $y$ when you know that $I_0'(z) = I_1(z) $, $ K_0'(z) = -K_1(z) $.

Comment: Ah, nicely done! I suppose this reveals that there is very little hope of an elementary solution...

Comment: And I should probably confess that I found this by finding the solution with a CAS, then extrapolated the form of substitution from the (very weird-looking) answer.

Comment: No, there's no way to get an elementary solution from that differential equation, as you can see by looking at a Frobenius solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to solve a second order linear equation instead

Except that it has variable coefficient but maybe you can work it..

$$y'=\frac{y^2}{x}-1$$
Substitute $v=\frac yx$

The equation becomes
$$v'=v^2-\frac 1x-\frac vx$$
Now substitute $v=-\frac {u'}u$
$$u''x+u'-u=0$$
Maybe you can try now the Lpalce transform or a serie solution ?